# How to get the handle of the currently active tab with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, window-handles

I want do find out what's the handle of the currently active chrome tab with Selenium. I can get all the handles with `driver.window_handles` and `driver.current_window_handle` to find out what handle selenium is focused on, but when i now change the tab manually, selenium is still focused on the old tab. How can i now change the focus to the active tab?

Comment: Why there is a manual intervention ? `but when I now change the tab manually,`

Comment: My plan was to make an automated chrome for my employees for several websites. So that they can use the selenium chrome normal and when they go to a certain wensite something automated happens. Therefore i need to know what tab is actally active

Answer (score 2):

To get the [window-handles](/questions/tagged/window-handles) of the currently active tab using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to [***switch_to.window()***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567464/how-to-switch-window-handles-using-selenium-and-python/57568925#57568925) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*number_of_windows_to_be()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python/51893230#51893230) and you can use the following solution:

```
windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
print(windows_before)
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://google.com')")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
windows_after = driver.window_handles
new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.title_contains("G"))
print(new_window)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium Switch Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690243/selenium-switch-tabs/53692407#53692407)
- [Switching into new window using Selenium after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082900/switching-into-new-window-using-selenium-after-button-click/47089023#47089023)

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to tab 1 using:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Whereas if you want to revert back to tab 0 you can use:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

There is also a way to make selenium switch tabs upon pressing CONTROL + TAB

```
self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

If you still can’t switch tabs, publish the entire chunk of code and We’ll take a look

Comment: My plan was to make an automated chrome for my employees for several websites. So that they can use the selenium chrome normal and when they go to a certain wensite something automated happens. Therefore i need to know what tab is actally active

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675923/selenium-how-to-get-the-number-of-tabs-opened-in-a-window) can help you identify the tab number on a website